# java: how to select only one cell in a jtable and not the whole row

Tags: java, swing, rendering, jtable, row

in a jTable, I want when a user clicks on a cell, this sentence to be printed on the screen :

```
I am cell in row X and column Y
```

where x and Y are the row and column of the clicked cell.
But what I am getting is : when I click for example the cell in row 1 and column 4
I get the following :

```
I am cell in row 1 and column 0
I am cell in row 1 and column 1
I am cell in row 1 and column 2
....
I am cell in row 1 and column N  ( N = number of columns)
```

i.e. the whole row is selected.

this is the code :

```
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
{

    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            if(isSelected) System.out.println("I am cell in row "+row+" and column "+column);



    return cell;

}
```

}

Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you meaning to remove highlight selected JTable row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CellRenderers are used for rendering the cell contents. If you want to find the cell in which the mouse clicked, use a MouseListener and in the mouseClicked method find the cell.

Answer (score 17):

You shouldn't use a cell renderer for this.

Enable cell selection on your table (using `setCellSelectionEnabled(true)`), then get the selection model of the table (using `getSelectionModel()`), and add a listener on this selection model. Each time an event is triggered, use `getSelectedRow()` and `getSelectedColumn()` to know which cell is selected.

Note that this will give you the selected cell, which can be modified using the mouse or the keyboard. If you just want to know where the mouse clicked, then see KDM's answer.

Comment: If you want to restrict the selection to allow only a single cell, like I did, you will want to call `setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);` as well.  In conjunction with `setCellSelectionEnabled(true)` this produces the desired effect quite nicely.

Answer (score 9):

```
myTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

myTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if(isSelected)` to `if (isSelected && hasFocus)`.  This will print for only the selected cell, rather than the selected row.

mKorbel's answer should also work...