# Mouse Event not working when clicking JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, mouseevent

I created a simple mouse event. When the user clicks the JTable it will fetch the records in the JTable and display them in the JTextField. In this case I am trying to display the ID from the Table into the Text Field.

```
public void fetchRec() {
    xtable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void rowClicked(MouseEvent evt){
            xtable =(JTable) evt.getSource();
            int row = xtable.rowAtPoint( evt.getPoint() );
            int column = xtable.columnAtPoint( evt.getPoint() );
            String s=xtable.getModel().getValueAt(row, column)+"";
            idLabelField.setText(s);
        }
    });
}
```

I am calling the method here but it keeps telling me that rowClicked method is unused. I don't understand how its unused? Everything else I am calling is working except this.

```
   public void bookDimensions() throws Exception {
    addTextLabels();
    addTextFields();
    addPanelButtons();
    addRecord();
    addTable();
    fetchRec();
  }
```

Comment: You are implementing a custom `MouseAdapter`, so what you need to do is to override one of the corresponding methods, see [`MouseAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html). So altogether, your `rowClicked()` should probably be `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)`. To make sure you actually override the correct method from the `MouseAdapter`, add the `@Override` annotation to the method.

Comment: Sidenote: There are better ways to do this. E.g. the solution Reto posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on cell selection and listen to the selection model instead of mouse events. See [java: how to select only one cell in a jtable and not the whole row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451200/java-how-to-select-only-one-cell-in-a-jtable-and-not-the-whole-row)

Comment: As mentioned above in a comment, *this* is the correct path to follow for table selections.