# How to select multiple rows without selecting the entire column in JTable Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

There is a JTable table, you need to select a continuous block of cells in a row, without selecting the entire column:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mpzg.png]

It is necessary to select cells D, E, F in line 1 and cells 0 with the value 6C in the second line, is this provided?
P.S.  I need this to process selected values, there is an option of course to increase the number of columns dynamically so that all the necessary values ​​fall into one line, but this looks like a crutch.

So, as if I select with the mouse, what happens on the screen. The same thing happens when using functions.

```
Table.setColumnSelectionInterval();
Table.setRowSelectionInterval()
```

Comment: A column is a group of cells arranged vertically.  A row is a group of cells arranged horizontally.  [How to select only one cell in a JTable and not the whole row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451200/java-how-to-select-only-one-cell-in-a-jtable-and-not-the-whole-row)

Comment: See [setCellSelectionEnabled](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#setCellSelectionEnabled(boolean)).